# Keyboard not showing when tableView.reloadData() inside textFieldDidBeginEditing

Tags: ios, swift

I put `UITextField` inside `UITableViewCell` and want to make highlight `tableViewCell` and unselected `tableViewCell` goes original color if user key-in inside each `UITextField`. So, I did like that.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    defaultIndex = textField.tag
    dynamicFormTable.reloadData()
}
```

But problem is **Keyboard** is not showing when I've added `dynamicFormTable.reloadData()`. Please let me know how to resolve it. Thanks.

Comment: Y u r reloading your tableView ? Reason ?

Comment: Textfield and Textview, while we are typing or begin to Type, we should not reload. I will stuck. May I know the specific reason.??

Comment: @McDonal_11 as I said, I want to make highlight `tableViewCell` when user key-in inside each `UITableTextField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will give good result, to avoid reloads

```
var cellBGColr = [Int : UIColor]()
var previouselectedRow = [Int]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for i in 0..<70 // numberOfRows
    {
       cellBGColr[i] = UIColor.white
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 70
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "table", for: indexPath) as! TblTableViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = cellBGColr[indexPath.row]
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {

    let cellPosition = textView.superview?.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tblView)
    let indPath : IndexPath = tblView.indexPathForRow(at: cellPosition!)!

    let cell = tblView.cellForRow(at: indPath) as! TblTableViewCell

    var previousSelectedCellRow : Int = -1 // FOR VALIDATION

    if previouselectedRow.count == 0 // FIRST EDIT
    {
        previouselectedRow.append(indPath.row)
    }
    else
    {
        previousSelectedCellRow = previouselectedRow[0]

        if previousSelectedCellRow == indPath.row // SAME ROW EDITING AGAIN
        {

        }
        else  // NEW ROW
        {
            let previousIndPath : IndexPath = IndexPath(row: previousSelectedCellRow, section: 0)

            if (tblView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.contains(previousIndPath))!
            {
                let previousCell = tblView.cellForRow(at: previousIndPath) as! TblTableViewCell

                previousCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

                cellBGColr[previousSelectedCellRow] = UIColor.white

            }
            else
            {
                cellBGColr[previousSelectedCellRow] = UIColor.white
            }

            previouselectedRow.remove(at: 0)
            previouselectedRow.append(indPath.row)

        }
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red // HERE YOU CAN CHANGE UR CELL COLOR

    cellBGColr[indPath.row] = UIColor.red // HERE STORED IN DICT
    return true
}
```

On scrolling your tableview, or somewhere you try to reload, cell background color will not change / reuse.

Comment: could you please provide the (unselected) rest cell background to be changed white color?

Comment: Logic may old. If u tried better in ur way, pls update.

Answer (score 0):

When `reloadData` is called it resigns first responder. But you can use `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` methods:

```
dynamicFormTable.beginUpdates()
dynamicFormTable.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: defaultIndex, section: 0)], with .none)
dynamicFormTable.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Above you mentioned is selected row will be highlight. But what I need to I need to grey out the rest. Sorry about I forgot to mention it.